# How do I specify slugifying code in this South migration?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have a model like:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
```

I want to add this NOT NULL field:

```
slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=255)
```

When I run "python manage.py schemamigration things --auto", I get prompted to enter Python code for my one-off default value.

What should I enter here in order to lowercase and slugify the existing titles?  And is there anything else that I have to do with the migration, before running 'migrate'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i'd probably leave it blank in the migration, and instead follow it with a [data migration](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations) creating the slugs there with some code